# How to implement IVR call feature in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, swift3, voip, ivr, vxml

I am a new developer working in swift 3 iOS. Pardon me in advance for any confusions and blunders as I am really new to this. So, I want to create an iPhone app for customer service.

For example, Like MyAirtel app where the users login and access their account information. I want to implement a Voice over IP call feature in this. The call is a Ip call without using any phone numbe - like a skype call - to the IVR system where a programmable voice ask us to press 1 for this and 2 for that. It connects to the database and retrieves information or routes the call to an agent whatever is required.

How can I do this? What are all the requirements? How does it work in developer terms?

Can someone please explain this? Simple explanation with references and softwares will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate a Voip phone client could be very complex in an App.
Best way could be using WebRTC, or getting some free opensources Voip (SIP) stacks.

The other part of your service is to create a voice IVR portal.
You have different solutions (using a basic free opensource Asterisk, or pay for a Saas service...).

Check you you really need to develop an application to place calls... you can use an already existing Application (as Zoiper, Dubango...), or use a standard phone call (Voip could be limited by the mobile operator).